# Localhost port running even after kill and freeing the port

Tags: python, node.js, express, localhost

This is a curious situation:

### Python folder

Let us say the path is `~/pyfolder/`

I run the command `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080` inside the folder. Now on `localhost:8080`, I get `index.html` which is inside the `pyfolder`.
I stop the server by killing the process, check that nothing is going on the port 8080.

### Node folder

Let us say the path is `~/webfolder/`
I run `PORT=8080 node server.js` inside the folder. I expect to see `~/webfolder/index.html`(i have setup express js route for `/` to show this file) on port 8080. But what is see is `~/pyfolder/index.html`. This is weird.

Furthermore, when a call is made to 8080, node console show a request being made on the port which is handled by express but still the page shown is from the python folder.

Can someone explain what is the problem here?

EDIT:
Also, the happens only on browser without incognito mode. As soon as I try this in incognito mode, everything runs fine.

Comment: I guess the browser caches the index file

Comment: cleaned the cache